# Adding user agent header to image download request

Tags: ios, webclient, user-agent, mvvmcross

I ran into a problem where a change in server configuration meant that all my attempts to download images with `MvxImageViewLoader` were getting redirected until it eventually gave up. After a lot of fretting, we finally discovered that the lack of a user-agent header in the http request was the culprit. So, two questions:

1) Despite the failure to load, no errors where produced by the MvxImageViewLoader and setting an `ErrorImagePath` didn't result in the error image being displayed instead. This seems wrong. I would have at least expected an error message in the debugger.

2) Is there a simple way to add a user-agent header? After looking at the source for the download cache plugin, I created my own version of `MvxHttpFileDownloader` which is exactly the same as the original except it creates my own version of `MvxFileDownloadRequest` which again, is exactly the same as the original, except I add the user agent header before starting the request. Then my version of `MvxHttpFileDownloader` is registered in `AppDelegate` replacing (I assume) the original. This seems a little heavy handed. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's not clear to me what the first question is.

   If there is a bug that `ErrorImagePath` was not used, then please log this (preferably with a reproduction sample) on http://github.com/slodge/mvvmcross/issues
2. No - I don't know of any simpler way to do this at present.

   The DownloadCache plugin provides a download cache of images. As a whole module, it's API is fairly simple - e.g. the image view loading can be replaced just by providing an alternative implementation for `IMvxImageHelper<TImage>`.

   Internally, the module also provides developers with some flexibility:

   - via interfaces - e.g. with the ability to override individual parts - e.g. `MvxHttpFileDownloader` can be overriden exactly as described in your question,
   - via some configuration options for some of the cache constants.

   Beyond these, there isn't any other API currently available. The reason for this is simple - just as with all of MvvmCross, the DownloadCache was built to meet the requirements of genuine apps - and these apps didn't require anything else. Indeed, the DownloadCache was really a replacement of [the MT.Dialog image loader](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Utilities/ImageLoader.cs) and the Windows built-in `Image` control downloading - both of which offer even fewer customisation hooks than the current DownloadCache does.

   If there are useful additions that people require, then these can of course be requested (or built and sent as Pull Requests) - and these may be included in a future library release .

   Alternatively, developers can also construct alternative implementations - especially using platform-specific networking stacks or using the new HttpClient networking libraries, which may overcome some of the [possible issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238809/mvxdynamicimagehelper-unreliable) with the MonoTouch Http stack.

Hope that helps

Stuart

Comment: The tricky part is that you can override `MvxHttpFileDownloader`, but `MvxHttpFileDownloader` is hardcoded to use `MvxFileDownloadRequest` (rather than getting something via IoC) so I had to re-implement both of them just to add one line to `MvxFileDownloadRequest`.