# MvvmCross: MvxImageViewLoader how to set DefaultImagePath property

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

How can I set the DefaultImagePath on MvxImageViewLoader?

How can I get the LocalResourcePath for an UImage?

```
 var imageViewLoader = new MvxImageViewLoader(() => imageView);
 imageViewLoader.DefaultImagePath = UIImage.FromBundle("images/Default.png");
 imageViewLoader.ErrorImagePath = UIImage.FromBundle("images/Error.png");
```

Answer (score 4):

Using resource image paths with  is discussed in [Using MvxImageViewLoader to load a resource image, is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462371/using-mvximageviewloader-to-load-a-resource-image-is-it-possible) using the `res:` prefix

```
 imageViewLoader.DefaultImagePath = ("res:images/Default.png");
```

---

There has also been a recent question saying `ErrorImagePath` was not working correctly in some http error cases - [Adding user agent header to image download request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344094/adding-user-agent-header-to-image-download-request) - but no reproduction/issue has been made on this yet.

Answer (score 1):

Could not get the above to work, the below though worked right away:

```
imageViewLoader.DefaultImagePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("Cover", "png");
imageViewLoader.ErrorImagePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("Cover", "png");
```