# Image in TableView (Subtitle) MVVM

Tags: uitableview, mvvm, xamarin, mvvmcross

This may seem like a silly question but I am having a hard time finding the correct answer.  I am writing an application using MVVMCross and Xamarin for iOS. In the application i want to use a TableView using the standard Subtitle Cell style. I am able to successfully bind to the title and detail text, but have so far been unsuccessful in binding the Image to a local file. Most examples I see are using images pulled from the web, whereas here i would like to use an image from the Resources folder. I am also trying to avoid having to write a custom cell.

How would you bind a local image to the standard Subtitle Cell style using MVVMCross and Xamarin?

Line of code in question:

```cs
var source = new MvxStandardTableViewSource (TableView, UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, new NSString( "CellID" ), "ImageURL Image; TitleText Title; DetailText EventDate");
```

Thanks!

Comment: You use a `res;` prefix - e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498656/mvvmcross-mvximageviewloader-how-to-set-defaultimagepath-property

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a converter:

```cs
public class ItemTypeToImageValueConverter : IMvxValueConverter
{
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string assetName = "unknown";

            switch ((ItemType)value) {
            case ItemType.SOMETHING:
                assetName = "something";
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ();
            }

            return "res:item_" + assetName + ".png";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}
```

Then to bind it to your UI:

```cs
private readonly MvxImageViewLoader typeImageViewLoader;

public ItemItemTableViewCell(IntPtr handle)
            : base(handle)
        {
            typeImageViewLoader = new MvxImageViewLoader(() => BackgroundImageView);

            this.DelayBind(() =>
                {
                    var set = this.CreateBindingSet<ItemItemTableViewCell, Item>();
                    set.Bind(typeImageViewLoader).To(vm => vm.Type).WithConversion("ItemTypeToImage");
                    set.Apply();
                });
        }
```